# Hiding a mat data table column in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-cdk

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="jan">

<mat-header-cell [hidden]="true" *matHeaderCellDef  style="font-size: 65%" class="white-text" fxHide [fxShow.gt-md]="true">
  Jan
</mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="font-size: 65%"> <span> </span> </mat-cell>
```

I am trying to hide a column in angular 4 . I tried to use `*ngIf` , but it says we are not allowed to use more than one component with `*` sign. Even `[hidden]` does not work.

Answer (score 3):

In your `mat-header-row`, you define the `columnsToDisplay`. You can use this field, to control which columns are shown:

#### component

```
columnsToDisplay = ['userName', 'age'];
```

#### template

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
```

For more details, see the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview).

> This means that by changing your column list provided to the rows, you
>   can easily re-order and include/exclude columns dynamically.

Comment: I have defined the columns to display, but I have to conditionally display the columns. I have a drop down , depending on its selection the column should be visible or hiden.

Comment: So when something is selected in your drop down, update the values of `columnsToDisplay` accordingly; you probably have to use the `(change)` event on your dropdown.

Comment: Thank you it worked but the order of columns in different. Any solution for that

Comment: Okay also it does not depend on the order of the template. Thank you I learned something :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `[hidden]` property for hiding HTML element when using Angular Material, its better to begin the tag with classic HTML tag.

In your case, use `<th></th>` instead of directly use `<mat-header-cell></mat-header-cell>`.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="jan">
  <th
    mat-header-cell
    [hidden]="true"
    *matHeaderCellDef
    style="font-size: 65%"
    class="white-text"
    fxHide
    [fxShow.gt-md]="true"
  >
    Jan
  </th>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="font-size: 65%">
    <span> </span>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Working example is available on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqejlg?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html).